# TensorFlow:What should be the first parameter for prediction using sess.run() in TensorFlow after loading a saved model.ckpt file?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to TensorFlow and machine learning. I am trying to classify two objects a cup and a pendrive (jpeg images). I have trained and exported a model.ckpt successfully. Now I am trying to restore the saved model.ckpt for prediction of an image. Here is the script:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
   print "...Model Loaded..."   
   x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, IMAGE_SIZE , IMAGE_SIZE , IMAGE_CHANNELS])
   y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_CLASSES])
   keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

   init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

   sess.run(init)
   my_classification = sess.run(___________ , feed_dict={x_:image})
   print 'Neural Network predicted', my_classification[0], "for your image"
```

In the above script what should I use as the first parameter in sess.run() ? I have read many stackoverflow and github posts but havent found a solution that works for my case. The TensorFlow Documentation is also not very clear.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow, while your variable values are restored (by var name) through saver.restore(), you still need to reconstruct the graph.  So the way you run it is the same way you train, except you no longer have the labels fed in, and you don't have to train through loops.  Instead you just feed in features once, and get the prediction.